# Spring OAuth2 java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am following the guide [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit) that has the following snippet of code for auditing Spring Security login attempts from Spring Boot Actuator

```
@Component
public class LoginAttemptsLogger {

    @EventListener
    public void auditEventHappened(
      AuditApplicationEvent auditApplicationEvent) {

        AuditEvent auditEvent = auditApplicationEvent.getAuditEvent();
        System.out.println("Principal " + auditEvent.getPrincipal() 
          + " - " + auditEvent.getType());

        WebAuthenticationDetails details = 
          (WebAuthenticationDetails) auditEvent.getData().get("details");
        System.out.println("Remote IP address: "
          + details.getRemoteAddress());
        System.out.println("  Session Id: " + details.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

But when I use this code I get the error

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails
```

I am using a stateless OAuth2 JWT security config using Spring Boot `1.5.10.RELEASE` with Spring Boot Actuator. If I remove the part about the `details` then it works fine.

**edit**: So I just discovered that the value returned by my details is different than the properties of `WebAuthenticationDetails`. My details contains grant_type, scope, and username instead of remoteAddress and sessionId needed to cast to `WebAuthenticationDetails`. Interestingly when I access the actuator endpoint `/auditevents` the value of the details field contains the remoteAddress and sessionId. Hmmm. So this definitely means it's because I'm using OAuth2 but I don't know what exactly is the cause.

**edit2**: I also just noticed it is only publishing events for the password/client_credentials grant type. If possible I would also like to use this same listener for the refresh_token grant type as well

**edit3**: Here is my Authorization Server config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${tokenSigningKey}")
    private String tokenSigningKey;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(tokenSigningKey);
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new CustomJwtJdbcTokenStore(accessTokenConverter(), dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomAccessTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't the tutorial for 1.5.2?

Comment: @LanceToth indeed. Perhaps that is the issue but I wouldn't think a breaking change like that would be in a incremental release. I will try swithcing to 1.5.2 and see if that fixes it

Comment: Btw, @LanceToth, the link to the tutorial is broken.

Comment: @JoshC oops, fixed.

Comment: So, @LanceToth, the tutorial worked for me using 1.5.10 with just username/password auth. Could the problem be with stateless OAuth2 JWT? Maybe the `Authentication` that is published by that `AuthenticationProvider` is different.

Comment: @JoshC Thanks for confirming that. I just edited my question and indeed I beleieve it is due to the OAuth2. I am also noticing it is only publishing events for the password grant type. If possible I would also like it to use this same handler for client authentication as well. The plot thickens

Comment: @zero01alpha, the behavior that I'm seeing is that it is publishing an `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails` (which does have sessionId and remoteAddress), so I think my setup is a bit different than yours. Do you think it would be helpful to post a bit more of your OAuth2 configuration, e.g. are you using `@EnableOAuth2Sso`?

Comment: @JoshC I just posted my entire authorization server config, I am not using `@EnableOAuthSso`

Comment: Thank you, @zero01alpha, that was very helpful as I had misinterpreted your use case until I saw your configuration. I've posted my answer below. Hopefully, it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `AuthenticationManager` is the one that publishes authentication success events, and it is only used by `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter`. This is why you only see it with one grant type (password) because this is the only `TokenGranter` that so happens to authenticate the resource owner.

With the remaining token grants, the authorization server is presented with an authorization code, a refresh token, or just trusts the client credentials. Since no owner is authenticated, no event is published.

It's arguable that the details that are incidentally published by `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` ought to be something other than a `LinkedHashMap`, but I'm thinking that you'll want to do something different anyway since you are more looking for a token event.

There isn't really a good injection point for what you want to do. The model for granting tokens is different than the model for authenticating users. For example, `TokenEndpoint` doesn't have access to the HTTP request, which you'd need in order to construct the kind of details object you want.

One thing you could do that is icky is extend `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` to customize how the client `authenticationManager` is built. It's not an intended extension point, but it works for me:

1. Extend `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`

   ```
   public class PublishingAuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration
       extends AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {

       @Autowired
       AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher;

       @Override
       public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           super.configure(http);

           http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
               .authenticationEventPublisher
                   (authenticationEventBuilder);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Switch out `@EnableAuthorizationServer` for

   ```
   @Import(
       {AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class, 
        PublishingAuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.class})
   ```

Not great, but it does give me an audit trail for the client auth of each token grant.

Comment: Also, I know that `spring-security-oauth2` is being replaced in Spring Security 5. You can check out the current state of affairs here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix and a bit more about roadmap here https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security

Comment: Super helpful! It would be nice if they had all oauth2 actions publish some type of event to plug in to, fingers crossed! Thanks again.